# Recovering BTLE Advertistement Packet

Tags: macos, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

In OSX (objective-c, xCode), is it possible to recover the advertisement packet (raw bytes) from a peripheral?

I've seen the following method in CBCentralManagerDelegate:
    `- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI;`

However, I believe the advertisementData dictionary abstracts away the raw bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, getting the raw bytes is not possible with CoreBluetooth. You should put your raw bytes into the manufacturer data (that, unfortunately, is unavailable for iOS-based peripherals).